# How to create or load module which is loaded with flat layout?

Tags: coreclr

By [core clr source code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr) I found that there are resource assemblies which are loaded with flat layout
I tried to create some FLAT resource assembly by myself, but I didn't succeed.

How can I create resource/satellite assembly with flat layout?